confluent cloud login using github actions
while trying to write a workflow in github actions to install confluent cli and also login using
confleunt login --no-browser it actual requires an external authentication from the browser by generating a link
spawn confluent login --prompt --no-browser
Enter your Confluent Cloud credentials:
Email: test@example.com
Navigate to the following link in your browser to authenticate:
https://login.confluent.io/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&code_challenge=73jrkz8SMbyb_MDTgyr8OD-jwx0AMkBX9yoztGBevUw&code_challenge_method=S256&client_id=oX2nvSKl5jvBKVgwehZfvR4K8RhsZIEs&redirect_uri=https://confluent.cloud/cli_callback&scope=email%20openid%20offline_access&state=yV-BY8YMmtDmtBntekhHBtgsuQfORF7gwTXpdDsirJI&audience=https://confluent.auth0.com/api/v2/&connection=tte-confluentcloud-kafka-sso

how can i login to confluent cloud via github actions ?
